# Does Our Love For Dying Animal/Person Help Them With Death & Rebirth

Tags: death, rebirth, love

Do our Hindu texts say whether our huge amount of love for a dying person or animal can have any kind of good or helpful effect on their death and rebirth ?

So before they’re dying we’re thinking of how much we love them and how good and wonderful they are. We’re sending them our best most loving thoughts and prayers—does this love reach them or help them as they die and take birth again ?

When a very noble gentle animal dies, does our love and loving energy we send them, can this be felt by their jiva or help them in any way as they take a new form ? Does Hinduism say anything about this ?

I guess I have two questions: Can the jiva somehow feel the love we’re sending their soul as they’re dying or close to death ?

Whether they can feel it or not, could it have a positive impact to help carry them through the death and rebirth journey ?

Thank you

Comment: I posted this cause I’m close to losing someone unfortunately  I’m sending my thoughts & prayers from a distance cause I love them so much. I don’t know if it’s helping at all. But I love them very much 